# Python SOQL Query Includes Syntax

Tags: python

This document defines how Querying Multi-Select Picklists
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

Using the workbench this provides results...

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, rie__Member_of_Campaign__c FROM CONTACT where rie__Member_of_Campaign__c includes ('FMS 2017 Program Exec Cmte')
```

How to set this up using Python is unclear.

This works in Python when there is only one value in...

```
qr = svc.query("SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM CONTACT where " + memberof + "= '" + eventId + "'")
```

But this does not since introducing a second set of parenthesis for the include values.

```
qr = svc.query("SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name   FROM CONTACT "where  "+ memberof + "includes ('" + eventId + "')")
```

I have tried this and it fails as well.

```
wherephrase = "where  "+ memberof + "includes (\'" + eventId + "')\"
qr = svc.query("SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name   FROM CONTACT wherephrase)
```

Comment: Seems you missed formatting. remove " start of where.  ```qr = svc.query("SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name   FROM CONTACT where  "+ memberof + "includes ('" + eventId + "')")
```

Comment: Tried the suggested syntax by removing the extra "="

Comment: Still gets an error

Comment: what error you get can put here?